# How can I create an executable jar without dependencies using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I want to package it not in a single executable jar for distribution. I need an executable to be something like main.jar and all dependencies to be in libs/*.jar

How can I make maven executable jar without preincluded into it dependencies libraries?

In [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven) there is a note by answered Dec 1 '10 at 10:46
André Aronsen, but that one simply doesn't work (failed s.a.descriptorRef is not set).

Comment: have you looked at onejar-maven-plugin?

http://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/

Comment: this plugin just do opposite - it includes all jars into one main jar archive, not in subdirectory.

Comment: I use Capsule, has more features than I need

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve this to a certain extent.

Firstly, you would create an [executable jar](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html) by configuring [maven jar plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) suitably.

You would then use maven assembly plugin to create a jar-with-dependencies, *excluding your project jar*.  To do this, you would create a descriptor file, say `src/main/assembly/descriptor.xml`, like this.

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
  <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Use it in your project like this.

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/descriptor.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
        [...]
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

You will end up getting two jars - one the executable jar created by your project and the other the jar-with-dependencies created by the assembly plugin.

Answer (score 14):

I prefer this a bit modified solution. Create Your executable jar with classpath set and copy all dependencies to given directory.

You don't need any additional files.

Dependencies are being copied during install phase.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <!-- optional -->
                        <!-- exclude copying test and provided dependencies -->
                        <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                        <excludeScope>provided</excludeScope>
                        <!-- optional -->
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I updated the answer to copy only runtime dependencies as described [here - copying the right dependencies](http://web.archive.org/web/20180321045645/http://code.bobarnott.com/2013/01/09/copying-the-right-dependencies-with-maven/). Test and provided dependencies are excluded.

> It turns out that if you want to exclude dependencies from both the test and provided scopes, you need to exclude the provided scope and include the runtime scope.

Comment: Thank you @Rafal, it works for me. Yes, the advantage is we dont need any additional file.

Comment: The link is dead.