# How make org.openrdf.rio parser supports Turtle documents?

Tags: rdf, openrdf, r2rml

I have a java project on Eclipse that read R2RML (.ttl) file. I am using `R2RMLReader` from `it.unibz.inf.ontop.r2rml.R2RMLReader` which uses Open RDF Rio `org.openrdf.rio.Rio`, here is the method code:

```
public static ArrayList<TripleMaps> readR2RMLFile() {
        String mappingFile= "/path/to/Desktop/r2rmlFile.ttl";

         R2RMLReader reader = null;
          try {
            reader = new R2RMLReader(mappingFile);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          ArrayList<OBDAMappingAxiom> axioms = reader.readMappings();
          for (OBDAMappingAxiom ax : axioms)
            System.out.println(ax);
        return null; 
    }
```

However, the R2RMLReader throws this error:

```
org.openrdf.rio.UnsupportedRDFormatException: No parser factory available for RDF format Turtle (mimeTypes=text/turtle, application/x-turtle; ext=ttl)
    at org.openrdf.rio.Rio.createParser(Rio.java:198)
    at it.unibz.inf.ontop.r2rml.R2RMLManager.<init>(R2RMLManager.java:71)
    at it.unibz.inf.ontop.r2rml.R2RMLReader.<init>(R2RMLReader.java:63)
    at it.unibz.inf.ontop.r2rml.R2RMLReader.<init>(R2RMLReader.java:54)
    at TripleMaps.readR2RMLFile(TripleMaps.java:170)
```

What am I missing? Are there any jar files that should I add to the project?

I see this implementation on many tutorials and they use .ttl file format. However, in my project it not working.

I looked into different solutions this [org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.UnsupportedRDFormatException for Turtle format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70435732/org-eclipse-rdf4j-rio-unsupportedrdformatexception-for-turtle-format)
and this [RDF4J RIO UnsupportedRDFormatException when adding data to an HTTPRepository using a stand-alone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40907324/rdf4j-rio-unsupportedrdformatexception-when-adding-data-to-an-httprepository-usi/40920378#40920378)

However, I am not using maven I downloaded all jar files and added it to the project.

I looked in http://archive.rdf4j.org/javadoc/sesame-2.8.9/org/openrdf/rio/RDFFormat.html , the openrdf/rio/RDFFormat should support Turtle.

> "The file extension .ttl is recommend for Turtle documents"

How make org.openrdf.rio parser supports Turtle documents?

Comment: if you don't use Maven for whatever reason, then indeed have to download the missing JARs and moreover, the correct version if those - that's exactly the point Maven makes way easier (most of the times ...)

Comment: what jars am I missing? because I added all needed jars, however it not support ttl format. How could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the actual Turtle parser implementation, which is contained in a separate jar file from the Sesame Rio parser APIs (see https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.openrdf.sesame/sesame-rio-turtle ).

As suggested in the comments as well, I'd urge you to save yourself a world of pain: use maven to solve these kinds of dependency problems.

Also this: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve of course, and I don't know what version of the Ontop platform you're using, but the mention of `org.openrdf` packages indicates it's an old version. That package name is from the old Sesame project, which was replaced by the Eclipse RDF4J more than 6 years ago. I'm also pretty sure that Ontop itself has updated its dependencies to use RDF4J instead of Sesame for a while now. You may want to try upgrading to a more recent version.

Comment: How could I use Maven? I never use it before. I am working on java project Eclipse, are there any useful tutorial on how to use maven to add dependency to my project?

Comment: If you google "getting started with maven in eclipse" you'll find several good tutorials. It may take a little investment to learn it, but worth it if you plan to do more java development in the future.