# Maven generating jar excluding all dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm very new to maven, so kindly bear with me.

i have a maven project with about 10 dependencies all of which are present in my local system. So I'm adding them to my classpath via `pom.xml` with `<scope>` being `system` and  `<systemPath>` giving path to the said dependencies. A rough structure of my pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>MAVEN_APP</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MAVEN_APP</name>
    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jar1</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency1</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/Details/Lib/jar1Name.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        ......
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jar10</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency10</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/Details/Lib/jar10Name.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*.*</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/Details</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*.*</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/Details/config</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*.*</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>

        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

This includes all the jars into my classpath and everything is running fine.

**But I would like to create a jar of my project with the jar containing only the source code(i.e., only the compiled java classes). It should not include any of the dependencies.**

To do this I included the `<plugins>` as shown above and executed `mvn clean -X install`. But I notice that all the underlying dependencies are being included within the jar.

Could somebody help me here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8326190/8357778

Firstly you add maven assembly plug-in and maven jar plug-in.

Secondly you create the job assembly with assembly.xml and describe into it how you want to create your jar.